# SSRS Expression With URL Illegal Character Error

Tags: url, reporting-services, expression, render, reportviewer

I have an expression that opens a report based on a condition being met.  The expression works without the URL if I point directly to the report, but since I am  basing this on conditions being met I can't just choose the report from the drop down list I need it to find the report once it knows what condition was met and what report to run.  I tried with just the report name in the expression but it can't find that report even with it deployed to the same location as the report its being called from so I figured I need to put the fully qualified location in but I keep getting illegal character errors.  I am searching for answers but if anyone can see what I may be doing wrong please let me know. I am new to SSRS. Thanks!

If I copy the URL to IE by itself I can go to the report in question.  It just gives me an error when I click on the image that the expression is behind.

An Error occurred during local report processing
Error in the application
Illegal characters in path

```
=IIF((Fields!MEAS_DEFINITION_TYPE.Value = "CSH"),"servername/Reports_TEST/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fDEV_FIT%2fFITDash_Trend24mo",Nothing)
```

Comment: Assuming you are using the Action properties of an image control? If so the then you should not need to do anything other than set the subreport name. If your drill through reports have parameters that you need to pass in then they will have to have the same names in both reports. I've just tested with a simple tablix, a textbox with an action to `Go to report` and then an expression to return the report name and it worked fine. Should be no difference using an image control in place of a textbox.

Comment: Just checked your previous question. You only need the report name, not the rdl extension.

Comment: Removing the .RDL solved my problem thank you!